# sum up column of times like 40m; 1d 2h 20m; 3h 10m

Tags: python, time, format

I have a column of time logs in the following format:

```
40m
1d 2h 20m
1h 10m
10m
2h 50m
```

How can I sum these up in Python and get the answer in seconds?

Comment: (1) parse each line to a number of seconds (2) add them

Comment: Did you tried anything with code?

Comment: I would start by writing a function that can process one string in the form `40m`. The split your strings and apply the function.

Comment: @toRex I only tried to come up with a basic solution in my head. Realised too late I'm expected to include some code. My bad :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are allowed to use external modules I suggest trying [pytimeparse](https://pypi.org/project/pytimeparse/). Example usage:

```
import pytimeparse
s1 = "40m"
s2 = "1d 2h 20m"
s3 = "1h 10m"
t1 = pytimeparse.parse(s1)
t2 = pytimeparse.parse(s2)
t3 = pytimeparse.parse(s3)
total = t1+t2+t3
print(total)
```

output:

```
101400
```

Explanation: `pytimeparse.parse` convert time-representing `str` to number of seconds. As it is external module you need to first install it: in this case it is sufficient to do `pip install pytimeparse`

Comment: Using modules is fine so I will mark this as the accepted answer since it's the easiest.

Answer (score 2):

Create a dictionary to store the value of `m,h,d` in seconds

```
m = {'m':60, 'd': 24*60*60, 'h': 60*60}

st="1d 2h 20m"
sum(int(i[:-1])*m[i[-1]] for i in st.split())
```

---

```
181200
```

Comment: you can calculate it for each row and then sum it up to get the final result

Comment: Nice solution to use a dictionary - that didn't even occur to me. Appreciate the cool solution!